# React Dropzone getting Stuck on Upload

Tags: reactjs, dropzone.js

Using React Dropzone: https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone

It was working wonderfully and "suddenly" it stopped working, but we're not sure when.

It gets stuck at the upload part. The render works, the dropzone is available, and you can click or drag a file over.

But it gets stuck at "Uploading now..." and never actually uploads anything now. But it was for awhile awhile.

I'm guessing it's just missing something small as we rarely update this file.

The form itself is at: http://hrockchurch.com/requests/
pw: HRockCreative

```
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'
import R from 'ramda'
import { Input } from 'react-bootstrap'

import utils from '../lib/utils'
import styles from '../lib/styles'
import Gett from '../lib/gett'

import FileList from './fileList'

export default class CustomDropzone extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    setValue: React.PropTypes.func,
    multiple: React.PropTypes.bool
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    setValue: utils.noop,
    multiple: true
  }

  state = {
    uploading: false,
    dragOver: false,
    files: []
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this)
    this.onDragOver = this.onDragOver.bind(this)
    this.onDragLeave = this.onDragLeave.bind(this)
    this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this)
    this.removeFile = this.removeFile.bind(this)
  }

  uploadFile(file) {
    this.setState({ uploading: true, dragOver: false })
    Gett.file
      .create(file)
      .then(gtFile => {
        this.addFile(gtFile)
        this.setState({ uploading: false })
      })
  }

  addFile(file) {
    const newFiles = this.state.files.concat(file)
    this.updateFiles(newFiles)
  }

  removeFile(file) {
    const newFiles = R.reject(f => f.id == file.id, this.state.files)
    this.updateFiles(newFiles)
  }

  updateFiles(files) {
    this.setState({ files: files })
    this.props.setValue(R.map(R.prop('url'), files))
  }

  onDrop(files) {
    if (this.state.uploading) return

    R.forEach(this.uploadFile, files)
  }

  onDragOver() {
    if (this.state.uploading) return

    this.setState({ dragOver: true })
  }

  onDragLeave() {
    if (this.state.uploading) return

    this.setState({ dragOver: false })
  }

  getMessage() {
    if (this.state.uploading) {
      return 'Uploading now...'
    }
    if (this.state.dragOver) {
      return 'Yeah, that\'s the right idea!'
    } else {
      return `Drop your file${this.props.multiple ? 's' : ''} here`
    }
  }

  renderDropzone() {
    if (!this.props.multiple && this.state.files.length >= 1) return null

    return (
      <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}
            onDragOver={this.onDragOver}
            onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave}
            style={styles.dropzone}
            disableClick={this.state.uploading}>
       <div>{this.getMessage()}</div>
    </Dropzone>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const label = this.props.label || utils.titleize(this.props.name)

    return (
      <div>
        <Input label={label}>

          {this.renderDropzone()}
          <FileList files={this.state.files} removeFile={this.removeFile} />
          {this.props.children}
        </Input>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my working example which also has server example https://github.com/rofrol/react-dropzone-progress-bar

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import request from 'superagent';
import { Line } from 'rc-progress';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    percent: 0
  }

  onDrop = files => {
    this.setState({ percent: 0 });
    let data = new FormData();
    files.forEach(file => {
      data.append('files[]', file, file.name);
    });

    let req = request.post('http://localhost:3001');
    req.on('progress', event => {
      let percent = Math.floor(event.percent);
      if (percent >= 100) {
        this.setState({ percent: 100 });
      } else {
        this.setState({ percent: percent });
      }
    });

    const that = this;
    req.send(data);
    req.end((err, res) => {
      console.log('Successfully uploaded');
    });

  };

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      border: '1px solid black'
    };
    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} className='dropzone-box'>
          <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload. {this.state.percent}</div>
          <Line percent={this.state.percent} strokeWidth='1' strokeColor='#2db7f5' strokeLinecap='square' />
        </Dropzone>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

set timeout value  (ex: timeout: 3000000 // 5 Minute)